# How to change Apple Id associated with iOS Developer program?

Tags: ios, app-store

I have enrolled for "iOS Developer Program". 
abc@xyz.com Apple id were used while enrolling for "iOS Developer Program" as an individual.

Now I want to change Apple Id associated with "iOS Developer program". Is it possible?

How to do it? Can I access same "iOS Developer program", using newly assigned Apple ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are steps to change Apple Id associated with iOS Developer Program:

1. Go to https://developer.apple.com/ and login. Note: Enter Apple Id that you want to change and currently associated with developer program.
2. Click on "Your Account" tab.
3. Click on "Account details", it will take user to "Sign in to manage your Apple Id" screen.
4. Enter same login details entered at step #1.
5. After login, You can edit your Apple ID. Note: New Apple ID should not be associated with another Apple Account, otherwise it will give an error.
6. Once you verify and confirm new Apple Id, you can login to developer program with New Apple Id.

Comment: I couldn't edit my Apple ID this way, there was no edit option next to it like there is for name and primary email.